# SMART Errors in Logwatch

Tags: centos, bad-sectors, logwatch, smartd

I have an older Dell Precision 530 running CentOS 5.5.  I am seeing these errors in logwatch:

> -------------------- Smartd Begin ------------------------
>
> Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
>   detected:     /dev/hdb - 48 Time(s)   1
>   unreadable sectors detected
>
> Offline uncorrectable sectors
>   detected:     /dev/hdb - 48 Time(s)   1
>   offline uncorrectable sectors detected

So I replaced hdb with a different drive I had lying around, and I still get the same errors.  I think it's highly unlikely that I'd get the same exact errors on two different drives, so I'm wondering what else could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that both drives have failed. On the other hand, it could be that the hard drives do not properly support S.M.A.R.T. and so are giving erroneous results.

I would try [badblocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks) (which manually reads and writes from/to each hard drive sector) to see if the drives are actually bad.

Comment: I tried running badblocks on the drive while it was unmounted, but it kept complaining that it couldn't do it because something was using it.  The drive is also using LVM, if that matters.  I thought umounting it was enough.

Comment: I needed to run it on /dev/mapper/storage, not /dev/hdb.  It ran but I still get the message.

Comment: You could try either running a read-only badblocks test, or removing the drive from your LVM group.

Comment: I just went ahead & replaced the drive.